# show first 3 element on click

Tags: jquery, html

I have the list perspective-list item Blogs,Case_Studies,Whitepapers with respective class.on click the list item it show the respective element in '.page-perspective' ie.If I click blogs it shows only blogs and hide other.If I click whitepapers it shows only whitepapers and hide others.In whitepapers I have four '.page-perspective'.I want to show first three whitepaper '.page-perspective'

```js
(function($) {
  function perspective_type() {
    $(".perspective-list a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".perspective-list a").parent().removeClass('active');
      $('.wrapper .page-perspective').show();
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.wrapper > :not(.' + href + ')').hide();
      $('.wrapper > .' + href + '').show();
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
    $(".perspective-list a").mouseover(
      function() {
        $(".perspective-list a").removeClass('hover');
        $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
      });
    $(".perspective-list a").mouseout(
      function() {
        $(".perspective-list a").each(function() {
          $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
        });
      });
    $('#perspectives .perspectiveReadurl', '#page_perspectives .perspectiveReadurl').find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
  }
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var href= 'Whitepapers'; 
jQuery('.perspective-list a.'+href+'').parent().addClass('active');
$('.wrapper > .'+href+'').show();
jQuery('.wrapper > :not(.'+href+')').hide();
    perspective_type();
  });

})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page_perspectives">
  <div class="view view-page-perspectives view-id-page_perspectives">
    <div class="perspective-list">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li class="">
          <a class="Blogs" href="Blogs">Blogs</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="Case_Studies" href="Case_Studies">Case Studies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a class="Whitepapers" href="Whitepapers">Whitepapers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="view-content">
      <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: block;">
            Whitepaper 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Blogs" style="display: none;">
            Blogs 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: block;">
            Whitepaper 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Case_Studies" style="display: none;">
            Case study 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Blogs" style="display: none;">
            Blogs 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-6 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: block;">
            Whitepaper 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-7 views-row-odd views-row-last">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: block;">
            Whitepaper 4
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.slice(0,3)` to show only first three results of your jQuery selector:

```js
(function($) {
  function perspective_type() {
    $(".perspective-list a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".perspective-list a").parent().removeClass('active');
      $('.wrapper .page-perspective').slice(0,3).show();
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.wrapper > :not(.' + href + ')').hide();
      $('.wrapper > .' + href + '').slice(0,3).show();
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
    $(".perspective-list a").mouseover(
      function() {
        $(".perspective-list a").removeClass('hover');
        $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
      });
    $(".perspective-list a").mouseout(
      function() {
        $(".perspective-list a").each(function() {
          $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
        });
      });
    $('#perspectives .perspectiveReadurl', '#page_perspectives .perspectiveReadurl').find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
  }
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.Whitepapers').slice(0,4).show();
    perspective_type();
  });

})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page_perspectives">
  <div class="view view-page-perspectives view-id-page_perspectives">
    <div class="perspective-list">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li class="">
          <a class="Blogs" href="Blogs">Blogs</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="Case_Studies" href="Case_Studies">Case Studies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a class="Whitepapers" href="Whitepapers">Whitepapers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="view-content">
      <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Blogs" style="display: none;">
            Blogs 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Case_Studies" style="display: none;">
            Case study 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Blogs" style="display: none;">
            Blogs 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-6 views-row-even">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-7 views-row-odd views-row-last">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="page-perspective row Whitepapers" style="display: none;">
            Whitepaper 4
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only problem with this approach if whitepapers is initially displayed it shows all whitepapers.

Comment: @SDhaliwal are number or order of whitepapers dynamically changing? If not so, we can initially give static hide or show classes to them. Otherwise we'll think about another solution.

Comment: See my edited answer. I added a code to hide the whitepapers from 3 to the end initially.

Comment: By the way, whitepapers come with `display:block`. Therefore they appear and disappear. Can't you provide they come with `display:none`? So that we show the first 3, instead of hiding the rest. Then this problem will go away.

Comment: I think if you do it that way it will face the same problem except inverse, i.e. they will all be hidden before a click. This again depends on user3386779

Comment: @SDhaliwal it won't affect click functions, it will be only run at the page load. see my modified code.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict your selector by using :lt and :gt jquery rules. 
Eg., how to get the first 3 elements those have class `Whitepapers`:

```
$('.Whitepapers:lt(3)')
```

Next 3 elements:

```
$('.Whitepapers:lt(6):gt(2)')
```